# Examining the binding structure in a free monad AST

Tags: haskell, free-monad

Take this simple base functor and other machinery for a free monad with binding terms:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Monad.Free

data ProgF r =
    FooF (Double -> r)
  | BarF Double (Int -> r)
  | EndF
  deriving Functor

type Program = Free ProgF

foo   = liftF (FooF id)
bar a = liftF (BarF a id)
```

And here's a simple program

```
prog :: Program Int
prog = do
  a <- foo
  bar a
```

It has the following (hand-crafted) AST:

```
prog =
  Free (FooF (\p0 ->
    Free (BarF p0 (\p1 ->
      Pure p1))
```

What I'd like to be able to do is reason about bound terms in the following way:

- look at the `Pure` term in the AST
- note the bound variables that occur there
- annotate the corresponding binding nodes in the AST

Annotating a free monad AST directly via a cofree comonad seems to be impossible without doing [some kind of pairing](http://dlaing.org/cofun/posts/free_and_cofree.html), but you could imagine getting to something like the following annotated AST (via, say, `Fix`) in which nodes binding variables that appear in `Pure` are annotated with `Just True`:

```
annotatedProg =
  Just False :< FooF (\p0 ->
    Just True :< BarF p0 (\p1 ->
      Nothing  :< EndF))
```

So: is there a way to inspect the bindings in a program like this in such an ad-hoc way?  I.e., without introducing a distinct variable type à la [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904048/printing-an-ast-with-variable-names), for example.

I suspect that this might be impossible to do.  Options like [`data-reify`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=data-reify) are attractive but it seems to be extremely difficult or impossible to make `ProgF` an instance of the requisite typeclasses (`Foldable`, `Traversable`, `MuRef`).

Is that intuition correct, or is there some means to do this that I haven't considered?  Note that I'm happy to entertain any gruesomely unsafe or dynamic means.

Comment: I suspect you'll be able to do this fairly easily for dags, but other structures will be bad.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm believing less and less that this is easy.  But I would love to be proved wrong! :)

Comment: I think the question could stand to be a bit clearer.

Comment: You're going to face difficulty since your AST has, essentially, infinite branching which will preclude a lot of traversable tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm satisfied that this is not possible to do by any 'sane' ad-hoc method, for much the same reason that it's not possible to examine the binding structure of e.g. `\a -> \b -> \c -> b + a`.